# How to show button based on dropdownlist selected item using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu

How to show button based on dropdownlist selected item using jQuery on page load. 
I want to use jQuery and not the C# page load.

I am using a dropdownlist and a button, and I want that if dropdownlist selected value is `1` then the button should be visible and if the selected value is 2 then `button.visible="false"`.

Comment: Use `change` event http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using it in `ready` event and check what is the selected value of the dropdown. Based on it you can set the button to hide.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 if($('#dropdownlistId').val()=='expected')
 {
  $('#buttonId').hide();
 }

});
```